# What does this quote containing generic.class mean in the helpfile of methods?

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to retrieve source code for a method. Looking at `?methods`, I see the following (emphasis mine):

> ...
>   The source code for all functions is available. For S3 functions exported from the namespace, enter the method at the command line as **generic.class**. 
>   ...

What does generic.class mean? Some examples on how to use this information to retrieve source code would be really helpful.

Comment: Like `summary` is a generic that applies to many classes, you can do `summary.data.frame` `summary.lm` `summary.table` etc etc

Comment: Ah, each of those words are placeholders! `generic = summary` and `class = data.frame` or `class = lm`.

Comment: There ya go - now you can answer your own question and reap the glorious internet points :-)